# What's the best way to compare logits to labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm comparing logits to labels in the loop:

```
  for r in range(logits.shape[0]):
    if labels[r] == np.argmax(logits[r]):
      guessed += 1.0
```

where `labels` is a 1D array of integer labels and `logits` is is a 2D array, with the 2nd dimension being the probabilities of the labels.

The above solution is a Python loop that's not very efficient. There ought to be a commonly used `numpy` or `tensorflow` shortcut to do that. Could you suggest one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the the max values at once by `np.argmax(logits,axis=1)`.  The following can replace the for loop to get the total number guessed:

```
guessed = np.sum(labels == np.argmax(logits,axis=1))
```